# Online version link for HTML import emails

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

We are using Sitecore ECM at our company and will be using the import HTML option for many campaigns. What I am not finding is how to include a 'see online version of this email' for imported HTML. Ideally, the campaign ID and item ID would get automatically added to a link we make in the header in the usual format.

> /sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_camp=223C8C5882A14C46BB3DBFE96E13D6B9&ec_as=85B29C2C3E0A4E9E8042DA09056E25FA&ec_url=%2f%3fsc_itemid%3d%7b054BA733-844B-4FD0-B7DA-983E80119388%7d%26amp%3bsc_lang%3den%26amp%3bsc_pd_view%3d1

Is there specific link syntax for our generalists to use to ensure a link back to the online version?

Answer (score 0):

To get the "view online" version to work your URL needs to be in the format:

`http://www.yoursite.com?sc_itemid=xxxxxxxxxxxx&sc_lang=en&sc_pd_view=1`

All links in ECM emails will have the RedirectURLPage.aspx as their path - this is used to trigger analytics.

Also you need to make sure that all the items are published to the web database for them to be available as "View Online".

Comment: Thanks GG. Since the sc_itemid is created after importing the HTML, there is no way for me to format the link in the correct manner since you can't edit the HTML once imported.

Comment: Can you explain the rationale behind using imported HTML? I think the HTML import isn't very sophisticated and to get an online version you'll need to create a Newsletter Message.

Comment: Time factor mainly, numerous unique designs that can't get dev'd into a custom newsletter in time. I am finding though the Simple HTML one time message can be edited after the campaign is created so technically, I can manually create the online version link after tracking down the correct ids. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see. No probs. Good luck with it.